# DynamoDB Array of String becomes Array of Objects

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I insert an array of string to DynamoDB:

```
[13, 12, 12, 4]
```

It becomes Array of Objects when I view it in DynamoDB:

```
[ { "S" : "13" }, { "S" : "12" }, { "S" : "12" }, { "S" : "4" }]
```

Is it reasonable? Do I need to do something to make my data being inserted as array of string?

Here is how I put my array to DynamoDB:

```
var params = {
   TableName: "MatchDate",
   Item:{
      position: [1, 3, 4, 5]
   }
};

DynamoDBClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
   //Some other code
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a single object (an array of strings) you need to set your attribute type to [String Set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)

Then you will get

```
"SS": ["13", "12" ,"12", "4"]
```

Or you can use Number Set

```
"NS": ["13", "12" ,"12", "4"]
```

EDIT: Try something like this in nodejs

```
var params = {
   TableName: "MatchDate",
   Item: {
   "position": {
      SS: [
         '12',
         '13',
         '4'
      ]
   }
};

DynamoDBClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
   //Some other code
});
```

Check here for [AWS Refernce of Javascript putItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property)

Comment: Where should I set this?

Comment: If you post your existing putItem command I can give you a better answer. For now I have updated the answer with a generic example. I think your're using php right?

Comment: I have edited my post and included the command i written in nodejs.